# Knife snapping to vertices

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to slice a cube corner to corner using snapping:
[image: Cube cut diagonally]

However, on closer inspection we've missed the vertex on the corner:

[image: missed vertex]

In fact we've added two more vertices. Bad cube, no biscuit!

I've tried using snap settings (see below) as well as using shift so that I don't introduce any new vertices into the mix and only allow the cut to occur at existing vertices.

[image: Snap settings]

Is there there a way to do this? Possibly increase the snap threshold? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: Why don't you select the two verts and then hit 'J'?

Comment: @JohnEason This would help only in this case, not if you in other cases try to cut from one vertex to somewhere else on the edge. Although learning the shortcut J can be useful in many ways too, but since the question starts off with the _Knife_ tool I focused on that. It's better to learn how to properly use the _Knife_ tool. The important thing here, trying to enable _Snapping_ does not work with the _Knife_, but there is an inherent snapping there.

Comment: Yes. I agree but in a simple case like this it's much quicker than using the Knife tool. The other problem some folks encounter is using 'F' to create the new edge instead of 'J' and then finding that they haven't actually cut the face!

Comment: @JohnEason Oh yes, confusing F and J is a problem for many, too. As I said, J would be useful and easy here, but this question showed me there is a lack of understanding how the _Knife_ tool works. Maybe you could add your own answer, at least the last paragraph of the question invites to suggest other methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Snapping* tool is not used by the *Knife* tool. Instead, the *Knife* has it's own snapping method which does not need to be enabled.

If the green square indicating the knife's position is hovered over an edge this turns yellow to indicate, if you now click the cut will be snapped to the edge. If you move over closer to a vertex, a red outline around the green square will indicate the knife is now snapping to the vertex.

[image: knife snapping]

If you look at the bottom status bar while the *Knife* tool is enabled, you can see additional options for snapping: holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> let's you snap to the center of an edge, holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> makes the knife ignore the snapping. You will find other options there, too like angle constraint, cut through etc.

[image: knife options]